# Python: How to plot time interval from a Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the a dataframe(`df`) which has the data of a Job being executed at different time intervals. It includes the following details about the execution of a job:

1. Job Start Time (`START`)
2. Job End Time (`END`)
3. Time Interval (`interval`) i.e., `END` - `START`.

A small part of dataframe is shown below.

**Dataframe(df):**

```
  END    |  START   |  interval
1423.0   |  1357.0  |    66.0
33277.0  |  33325.0 |   -48.0
42284.0  |  42250.0 |    34.0
53466.0  |  53218.0 |   248.0
62158.0  |  62073.0 |    85.0
```

I want to plot a graph with the `x-axis` as the timestamp and the `y-axis` with the `interval`. I tried to do it with the `START` time but it is not giving the correct result. How can we do this?

**Code**

```
fig_dims = (12, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)

sns.lineplot(x = 'START', y = 'interval', data = df, ax = ax)
```

**Output**
[image]

**Required Output**
`x-axis` - Timestamp
`y-axis` - Interval

Comment: What timestamp would a start value of 1357 be?

Comment: It will be 1357

Comment: Then I am not exactly sure why the current plot is not what you want? The x-axis shows the values from 0 up to 1*10^9, which is the range of the `START` column, and the y-axis shows the interval, which can have both positive and negative values.

Comment: Yes, I get it but this graph is not making any sense, is there a different way to plot this so that I can infer something?

Comment: That completely depends on what you are trying to infer. Because you have such a long range of values that shift up and down quite a bit the line chart get compressed quite heavily using the default size. You could try increasing the size of plot (mainly the width), however you might end up with an extremely large plot before you can actually can see the individual line.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on a different type of plot that will be more useful in such a case?

Comment: What is the index of this dataframe? Is it just numbers [0,1,2,3,...]?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested alternative plotting methods to visualise this data:

1. Histogram of the y-axis. Check the distribution of time intervals

   `df.plot.hist(by='interval', bins=10) #test varying the bin size`
2. Plot smaller subsets of the data if the order is important e.g.
   `df[:100].plot()` furthermore, if there is periodicity in the data, e.g. `daily`, `hourly` etc. you could plot each hour on top of each other (in a different colour) to compare the differences between periods.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Otherwise please accept the answer